# How to keep OS X server up after booting without user having to sign in?

Tags: boot, ups, osx-yosemite

I've been having this problem now for quite awhile, and it's really starting to cause some major issues for my setup.

At my previous job, this server was UPS-protected, so whenever there was an small power outage, it was never a big deal.  At the time, it was running Mountain Lion with OS X Server.  The server moved with me to my new job, and since then, I have upgraded to Mavericks and then to Yosemite, but no longer have UPS protection.

It is a fairly powerful machine, and because of its USB 3.0 support, ideally, I'd like to setup a ZFS pool in FreeNAS that is always on, as well as a few other services that I use on a regular basis.

I have checked the option in System Preferences that tells it to boot back up after power failure (or whatever), but the real problem seems to be the fact that after it boots up, I am presented with the Login screen, and if I don't login within about 60 seconds, it shuts back down completely.

If I am working remote or am not in the room to notice (and I mostly run this thing headless), it completely shuts back down after about 60 seconds of inactivity if no users log in.  This creates some obvious issues -- the least of which is still pretty annoying -- the fact that xRDP is apparently running under ~/LaunchDaemons  or something.  I am using Bluetooth keyboard/mouse with this box for aesthetic purposes, so I'm not even able to RDP quickly from a laptop to login before it shuts back down if my peripherals are low on battery or something.  This is because xRDP is not already running at the boot screen.  This should be an easy fix, but by possibly placing it in /Library/LaunchDaemons or whatever, but like I said, that is the least of my annoyances at this point.

It just really sucks to be working remote and have to call my wife to boot up this server and then log into it.  And God forbid she has to go find batteries or a USB keyboard or something, or worse yet, she is not at home and I am out of luck for a few hours if I need access to this server.  I typically work about 45 minutes away, so gaining physical access in this scenario would not be worth the time and effort.

For what it's worth, my home router is running DD-WRT, and I don't recall ever having successfully gotten WOL to work with this box (or if I did, I was not able to login in time to prevent the automatic shutdown).

My questions are as follows:

1. Would the easiest fix just be to invest in UPS for this machine to possibly prevent this issue from occurring, even though this seems to be skirting around the actual root cause?
2. Is there something obvious that I am overlooking that could easily prevent this?
3. Is this an actual bug in OS X, or a flaw in my particular configuration somewhere?

I realize this question could also go in Super User, but given the nature of it being server-related, I figured I'd post it here.  I need this box available as a server -- not just a semi-available computer.

Just to give an example, whenever this happens, I have to boot the Mac Mini, Sign in, launch VirtualBox, launch Terminal, and run the following:

`vboxmanage startvm "FREENAS"` (wait for FreeNAS to start up)

`mountzfs` (which mounts my FreeNAS ZFS pool via AFP)

`open /Applications/Plex\ Media\ Server.app/`

`transmission-daemon -g ~/.transmission-daemon`

These are things that I want to be always running, not to mention the obvious Apache, Nginx, SSH, etc.  I have Googled off and on for months until my eyes bleed, all to no avail.  Hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

**EDIT**: *I recently ran Onyx while still on Yosemite (didn't help), and then upgraded to El Capitan, which also did not help.  This issue is still occurring.*

Comment: Are you sure you want to run OS X? It never was a very good server. Unless you absolutely need it for something that no other OS can do, then you're probably best off to use another OS.

Comment: I have a few different reasons for running OSX as a server. My ideal lab environment would be rack-mounted ESX hosts running multiple Linux and Windows VMs. Believe me, I realize that OS X is less-than-ideal as a server, but my reasons are strictly hardware/resource-based.  It is the most powerful and reliable machine that I own, which supports USB 3.0. My main goal is to run FreeNAS in VirtualBox from a USB drive and have a ZFS pool consisting of the 2 internal SATAs, 2 external USB 3.0 SATAs, and 2 external SSDs. This requires high availability, and OSX is currently the only guy for the job.

Comment: Is FileVault turned on on this Mac? It sounds to me like it is because an encrypted mac boots to the logon screen first, but the OS isn't running at this point. Since the OS isn't running, the Mac cannot regulate temperature, or monitor other vital systems, and protect itself if it overheats or something. Thus it will only run a few minutes to allow someone the opportunity to log back on, but shuts off to protect itself if no one does. If FileVault is not on, then this is odd behavior.

Comment: @Paperlantern - that is good advice.  I will double-check and come back with results.  This information could prove to be very helpful.  If it turns out this is correct, and I test successfully, then I would advise you to post your comment as answer which I would gladly accept, if this turns out to be the case.  I am currently out of town, but will be back to test this out well-before the bounty expires.

Comment: @Paperlantern - UPDATE:  I am back in town with access to the Mac Mini again, and I have confirmed that FileVault was indeed enabled.  However, the decryption is a slow process and right now is telling me that it has 3 days remaining to decrypt `Server HD` (1TB internal SATA).  This should still allow time for me to confirm your theory before the bounty expires, at which time you should re-post your comment as an answer.  If this is indeed the case, which I have a suspicion it is, then I greatly appreciate your help in this matter.

Comment: @Paperlantern - the decryption is complete, and so far, everything is looking good.  Please re-post your comment in the form of an answer, and I will accept it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like FileVault is turned on because an encrypted mac boots to the logon screen first, but the OS isn't running at this point. Since the OS isn't running, the Mac cannot regulate temperature, or monitor other vital systems, and take action if it overheats. Thus it will only run a few minutes to allow someone the opportunity to log back on, but shuts off to protect itself if no one does. If FileVault is not on, then this is odd behavior.